# Как вывести на консоль данные температуры из Json?C#

Tags: c#, json.net

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace Weather
{
   class Program
   {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = "http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/findq=London&units=metric&appid=439d4b804bc8187953eb36d2a8c26a02";

            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

            string response;

            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
      

            WeatherResponse weatherResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WeatherResponse>(response);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Нужно заоверрайдить метод `ToString()` в классе `WeatherResponse`, и затем вызвать `Console.WriteLine(weatherResponse.ToString());` или, если не ошибаюсь, можно просто `Console.WriteLine(weatherResponse);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше использовать [`HttpClient`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8) вместо устаревшего `HttpWebRequest`.

```csharp
class Program
{
    private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            WeatherResponse weatherResponse = await GetApiResponseAsync<WeatherResponse>("https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=London&units=metric&appid=439d4b804bc8187953eb36d2a8c26a02");

            foreach (WeatherData weatherData in weatherResponse.list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(weatherData.name + ": " + weatherData.main.temp + " °C");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static async Task<T> GetApiResponseAsync<T>(string url)
    {
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
        }
    }
}
```

Данные.

```csharp
public class Coord
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lon { get; set; }
}

public class Main
{
    public int temp { get; set; }
    public int pressure { get; set; }
    public int humidity { get; set; }
    public int temp_min { get; set; }
    public int temp_max { get; set; }
}

public class Wind
{
    public double speed { get; set; }
    public int deg { get; set; }
}

public class Sys
{
    public string country { get; set; }
}

public class Clouds
{
    public int all { get; set; }
}

public class Weather
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string main { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
}

public class WeatherData
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Coord coord { get; set; }
    public Main main { get; set; }
    public int dt { get; set; }
    public Wind wind { get; set; }
    public Sys sys { get; set; }
    public object rain { get; set; }
    public object snow { get; set; }
    public Clouds clouds { get; set; }
    public List<Weather> weather { get; set; }
}

public class WeatherResponse
{
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string cod { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
    public List<WeatherData> list { get; set; }
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
London: 7 °C
```

Comment: уже решил, все равно спасибо